# How to get a the data-testid from a DOM component?

Tags: reactjs, dom, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my React project, sometimes a dynamically generated UUID needs to be added to the a `data-testid` value to ensure uniqueness amongst duplicate components in the DOM.

I have a test situation where I can grab the element I want.  Now I want to get the dynamically generated data-testid from it. I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
const questionDropdown = queryAllByText('Free Text')[0];
console.log(questionDropdown.getAttribute('data-testid'));
```

Any suggestions how to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a dataset so you can get it like this:

```
console.log(questionDropdown.dataset.testid);
```

If you have an expected result you can test it with `testing-library/jest-dom`:

```
expect(questionDropdown).toHaveAttribute("data-testid", "test-id");
```

Doc: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveattribute

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do it!

So, I have a Semantic-UI Dropdown with a dynamically generated `data-testid`.  The trick to getting the element is simply to use Regex, like this:

```
const questionTypeDropdown = getByTestId(/conditional-task-question-type/);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm revisiting this.  I believe that the answer from `adesuriey` works great if you're dealing with conventional text, say in an Input element.  But in the Semantic UI Dropdown it does not appear to work.

I think the problem lies with finding the correct ancestor element. I've tried many things but with no success.